# How to detect underscore in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have a `regex` expression in order to test my password : at least one **digit**, at least one **upper letter**,at least one **lower letter** and at least one special character.

```
/^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w\s])/
```

But **underscore** is not recognized as `special character`.

How can I improve this ?

Comment: `[^\w\s]` does not match `_`. Replace with `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that works. Please post it as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Note that imposing character-class password requirements like this is considered bad practice (see e.g. [NIST Guidelines for Memorized Secret Verifiers](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#-5112-memorized-secret-verifiers)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that, for JavaScript, `\w` represents:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

So you are avoiding `_` implicitly.

## Explaination

This part of your regex:

```
(?=.*?[^\w\s]) // Match special character
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s])
```

## Bibliography

> The \w metacharacter is used to find a word character.
>
> A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _
> (underscore) character.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp

Comment: I mean underscore is not a part of `special character`.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai The problem is that you are doing `[^\w\s]` which is equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]`. So, the definition of _special character_ is not a letter, not a number, not space and not an underscore.